# Having a "Device Error" while loading Ubuntu after a fresh dual install with Windows 10 on a Lenovo E595

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, 23.10, nvme

I have an NVMe with Windows installed and another SSD with freshly installed Ubuntu 23.10. I followed the best practices and configured BIOS in UEFI only mode, turned off Fast Boot and Secure Boot. In the boot priority list I moved the newly added partition called 'ubuntu'. Whenever I try to load my PC I get the following error message:

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Device Error, buffersize 0
Failed to load image : Device Error
start_image() returned Device Error
```

After that it restarts. Can restart 5-10 in a row and then a grub menu for choosing os pops up and I can enter my OS. I tried to repair boot, but it doesn't seem to fix my problem. I have saved pastebin [before](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4cHQnHJMjH/) and [after](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ksWPMyhmGw/) repair.

After Boot-Repair:

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sda2,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in sda2/fstab
Mount /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/etc/default/grub

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sda2 ======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0019,001A,0000,0018,0016,0017,001B
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1048b8b6-122d-476e-8bab-020ce4388a81,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...I................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2fc96359-a4c8-4f05-9747-7a64bede9a29,0x800,0x219800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0016* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0017* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0018* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot0019* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001A* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001B* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot001C  Regulatory Information    FvFile(e4a83242-deee-f12e-15ff-0102036cc3ce)

uname -r
6.5.0-14-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
df /dev/sda1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0019,001A,0000,0018,0016,0017,001B
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1048b8b6-122d-476e-8bab-020ce4388a81,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...I................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2fc96359-a4c8-4f05-9747-7a64bede9a29,0x800,0x219800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0016* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0017* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0018* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot0019* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001A* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001B* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot001C  Regulatory Information    FvFile(e4a83242-deee-f12e-15ff-0102036cc3ce)
Warning: NVram was not modified.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 23.10 entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 23.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 23.10 on sda2
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic root=UUID=9d4aed30-2c8c-4409-8025-989cc77864b1 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/sda2      ext4   79G  5.9G   69G   8% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: R11ET48W (1.28 )(1.28) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0019,001A,0000,0018,0016,0017,001B
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1048b8b6-122d-476e-8bab-020ce4388a81,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...I................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,2fc96359-a4c8-4f05-9747-7a64bede9a29,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0016* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0017* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0018* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot0019* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001A* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001B* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot001C  Regulatory Information    FvFile(e4a83242-deee-f12e-15ff-0102036cc3ce)

f2c9c5c28ef51a83d75db5d108b1a310   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
1d99ff510dac8535d215797ad5e69230   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
1d99ff510dac8535d215797ad5e69230   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
f2c9c5c28ef51a83d75db5d108b1a310   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
46288d3cb6a91cb97d25474930f95dfb   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-has-bad-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda4    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 932AAF89-B2D9-414B-81E9-184E99098F1C
             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616  999118087 998878472 476.3G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 999118848 1000212479   1093632   534M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk identifier: EEEA8F71-BB24-421A-B7EF-7E6E59A668B1
         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
sda2    2203648 169975807 167772160    80G Linux filesystem
sda3  169975808 222404607  52428800    25G Linux swap
sda4  222404608 937699327 715294720 341.1G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:480GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA KINGSTON SA400S3:;
1:1049kB:1128MB:1127MB:fat32::boot, esp;
2:1128MB:87.0GB:85.9GB:ext4::;
3:87.0GB:114GB:26.8GB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
4:114GB:480GB:366GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:HFM512GDHTNG-8710B:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
3:123MB:512GB:511GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:512GB:512GB:560MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                
├─sda1      vfat   E25D-B272                            2fc96359-a4c8-4f05-9747-7a64bede9a29       
├─sda2      ext4   9d4aed30-2c8c-4409-8025-989cc77864b1 a3766f3e-3315-4dd6-93f2-e3cceab11a51       
├─sda3      swap   46ce0379-b4a6-4e24-8a2a-52ab8848342c 6ebb1041-67ff-4dbe-b160-ef5f09dde286       
└─sda4      ext4   e1909ae5-24d2-4bcc-90ea-00e7232480d6 e06015c6-74fb-44fb-82c2-97f66d23dc2a       
nvme0n1                                                                                            
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat   8058-5B86                            1048b8b6-122d-476e-8bab-020ce4388a81       EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                             e195c97a-43f7-4575-a3eb-d7307dd8e363       Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs   6A465BC2465B8DA7                     7e5b3bd3-b3ec-4999-b7f2-2750b193a042       Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p4 ntfs   26BEE570BEE53947                     3c7d9724-9c51-4028-8e46-f3f8e65f81fc       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                  64.4M  33% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3                  96.3G  80% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                  88.6M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/sda2                       68.3G   8% /
/dev/sda4                      317.5G   0% /home
efivarfs                       110.1K  25% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1                 vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3                 fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4                 fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda4                      ext4            rw,relatime

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 9d4aed30-2c8c-4409-8025-989cc77864b1 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   9d4aed30-2c8c-4409-8025-989cc77864b1
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-8058-5B86
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9d4aed30-2c8c-4409-8025-989cc77864b1 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/46ce0379-b4a6-4e24-8a2a-52ab8848342c none swap sw 0 0
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e1909ae5-24d2-4bcc-90ea-00e7232480d6 /home ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
UUID=E25D-B272  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  57.177825928 = 61.394223104   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  11.595317841 = 12.450377728   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  11.595317841 = 12.450377728   boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic                  1
  11.595317841 = 12.450377728   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  11.050777435 = 11.865681920   boot/initrd.img                                4
  11.050777435 = 11.865681920   boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic               4
  11.050777435 = 11.865681920   boot/initrd.img.old                            4

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18228 Oct  2 16:23 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Oct  2 16:23 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14459 Oct  2 16:23 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Oct  2 16:23 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Oct  2 16:23 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Oct  2 16:23 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Sep  6 03:36 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct  2 16:23 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Oct  2 16:23 41_custom
```

Comment: You might need to add/remove driver modules loaded by initramfs